# Como detectar listener de otra clase en Swing?

Tags: java, java-swing, windows

me pregunta es la siguiente: Yo tengo 2 clases principales, en una de las clases existen varios botones que tienen integrado un listener cada uno (Vamos a llamarla clase 2), hasta ahí todo bien pero ahora quiero saber si es posible detectar o saber cuando se a disparado un listener de la clase 2 desde la clase 1. Es posible detectar algo así? O tendría que cambiar de estrategia para poder detectar eso?

Comment: No está muy claro. Normalmente lo que se dispara es un *evento*, y los comoponentes tendrán *un conjunto* de listeners (que puede tener solo uno, o varios) ¿Quieres decir que tienes que detectar que ha sucedido un evento?

Comment: Exacto, tengo que detectar que sucedio un evento en la clase 2.

Comment: Pues para eso simplemente añade a la instancia de la clase 2 un listener que invoque al método que quieras de la clase 1. Precisamente los listeners son la lógica llamada cuando se detecta un evento.

Comment: Okey, muchas gracias. No se me había ocurrido algo así jaja.